# Take output of net group command and make it a list of users

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I want to take the output of a "net group" command and parse it so that the group members are a list. I don't have access any of the actual domain utilities except for this. (So Get-ADGroupMember isn't an option)

```
net group /domain MyADGroup

The request will be processed at a domain controller for domain encana.com.

Group name     MyADGroup
Comment        Sccm Deployment

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

MemberA             MemberB         MemberC
.
.
.
MemberZ

The command completed successfully.
```

What I would like is a file that just has

MemberA
MemberB
MemberC
.
.
.
MemberZ

It also has to be automated so I can schedule it to run periodically.
What I have so far is this
In command prompt:

```
net group /domain MyADGroup |more +8 > output.txt
```

In power shell:

```
(Get-Content output.txt)|ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "The command completed successfully.", ""}| ForEach-Object { $_ -replace " ", "`n`r"}|Set-Content output2.txt
```

I can probably put these both into a batch file. The output file has a boat load of extra lines but the tool I am importing with will happily ignore them. I'd just like something a little more streamlined without the million extra lines.

Comment: You can get a command's output with the `for` command. Type `for /?` for help.

Comment: Please learn to [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code properly! Also, please regard that this is not a free code writing service, so you have to try it yourself, share your efforts and describe precisely where you are stuck! Read this help topic: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a little script that first saves all groups to an "array" and then outputs them all. You can change it as your needs demand. Test it on WinServer 2003 and WinServer 2012. Hope it helps.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "count=0"

for /f "delims=* skip=4" %%i in ('net group') do (
    set /a "count+=1"
    set "groups[!count!]=%%i"
)

set /a "count-=1"
for /l %%i in (1,1,!count!) do (
   echo(!groups[%%i]!
)
```

Comment: Close to what I need. I just need one group but I think I can adapt this to what I need. Thanks!